# Routing Issues in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, routes

Hey I am trying to send an email on the click of a link...

Here is my link:

```
<%=link_to 'Hello', {:action => :contact}%>
```

In My controller I have:

```
 def contact
   Contact.contact_form.deliver
 end
```

My Mailer:

```
class Contact < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "****"
  default to: "****"

  def contact_form
    mail(:subject => "Registered")
  end


end
```

and in my routes I have:

```
  resources :pages do
  put :contact, :on => :collection
  end
```

However I am getting the error...

**Unknown action**

The action 'show' could not be found for PagesController

Pulling my hair out over this out, cant see what the issue is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your route is defining a PUT request, but the link_to is making a GET request. You can either change the route to use `get`, or change link_to to button_to  and specify the PUT method. I personally would go with the latter since it's bad practice to have a GET request do this.

```
<%= button_to 'Hello', contact_pages_path, :method => :put %>
```

Comment: thanks, but this has just changed the error to The action 'update' could not be found for PagesController instead of show

Answer (score 0):

change the following line:

```
<%=link_to 'Hello', {:action => :contact} %>
```

To

```
<%=link_to 'Hello', contact_pages_path, :method => :put %>
```